# No errors but does not run through the whole form script to send email

Tags: php, html, forms

Form not sending I have multiple forms on different pages of the site they are all programmed the same. I have 2 though that will not work when every other form works fine. I am attaching code for the short on and seeing any has any idea why the other forms would work but these would not even though programmed identically other then the inputs it is pulling as they are for different forms.

I have tried simplifying code to see where it may be hanging up tried echoing the errors but I get none and so I am at a lose wondering if I am just missing something silly

**FORM ON THE PAGE**

```
    <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-9">
                  <form method="post" action="contactprocess.php" `enter code 
                     here`class="form-contact">
                      <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-lg-5">
                              <div class="form-group">
                                  <input class="form-control" name="name" 
    type="text" placeholder="Enter your name" required>
                              </div>
                              <div class="form-group">
                                  <input class="form-control" name="email" 
    type="text" placeholder="Enter email address" required>
                              </div>
                              <div class="form-group">
                                  <input class="form-control" name="subject" 
    type="text" placeholder="Enter Subject">
                              </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-lg-7">
                              <div class="form-group">
                                  <textarea class="form-control different- 
   control w-100" name="textarea" id="textarea" cols="30" rows="6" 
   placeholder="Enter Message"></textarea>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group text-center text-md-right">
                          <button type="submit" class="btn active btn-- 
   leftBorder">Send Message</button>
                      </div>
                  </form>
```

**PHP SCRIPT**

```
    <?php

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $name = $_POST['name'] ;
    $email = $_POST['email'] ;
    $subject = $_POST['subject'] ;
    $textarea = $_POST['textarea'] ;
    $mailto = "xxx@xxxx.com";



    $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

    $body =     '<html><body>' ;
    $body .=    "<h1> Contact Form </h1>" ;
    $body .=    '<table rules="all" style="border-color: #666;" 
    cellpadding="10">';
    $body .=    "<tr><td><strong> Name: </strong></td><td>"  .$name . 
    "</td><td><strong> Email: </strong></td><td>"  .$email . "</td></tr>" ;
    $body .=    "<tr><td><strong> Message: </strong></td><td>"  
    .$textarea . "</td></tr>" ;
    $body .=    "</table>" ;
    $body .=    "</body></html>" ;

    mail ($mailto, $subject, $body, $headers) ;
    header ("Location: contactsuccesss.html") ;

    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Add the following to the top of your `php` ..  `ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);`  --  This will le t you know if there's a fatal error stopping your script ..

Comment: you should have a variable catch the result of calling mail() and test if it worked. Like $didMail = mail($mailto, $subject, $body, $headers); then use an if statement to verify it was sent since $didMail is now a boolean value

Comment: Yeah still not getting errors thank you for the suggestion

Comment: if you put `print_r($_POST)` before `if (isset($_POST['submit']))` and submit your form do you get any output?

Comment: When I do that I get an array of all values like it should
Array ( [name] => test [email] => test [subject] => test [textarea] => test )

Comment: I have now run multiple test and it is getting a 200 status so it should be running does any one see an error in the coding I am missing because it seems to be getting queued due to TFFB can not see any reason for this myself though as I have been trouble the same code hoping I am just not seeing something becuase it my own code

Comment: I finally went with this format 
<?php 
$ToEmail = 'xxx@xxx.com'; 
$EmailSubject = 'Site contact form'; 
$mailheader = "From: ".$_POST["email"]."\r\n"; 
$mailheader .= "Reply-To: ".$_POST["email"]."\r\n"; 
$mailheader .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n"; 
$MESSAGE_BODY = "Name: ".$_POST["name"]."<br></br>"; 
$MESSAGE_BODY .= "Email: ".$_POST["email"]."<br></br>"; 
$MESSAGE_BODY .= "Comment: ".nl2br($_POST["textarea"])."<br></br>"; 
mail($ToEmail, $EmailSubject, $MESSAGE_BODY, $mailheader) or die ("Failure"); 
header ("Location: contactsuccess.html") ;
?>